# Stopwatch has only 0ms

Tags: c#, .net, stopwatch

I've got QuickSort and Test Class for that sort.
Stopwatch does not work, always 0ms.

Task is to implement the specified algorithm - design the program as a console application. I need to estimate the execution time of the algorithm depending on the length of the source data.

**QuickSort**

```
public static void Sorting(int[] array, int first, int last)
{
    int x = array[(last - first) / 2 + first];
    int temp;

    int i = first;
    int j = last;

    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (array[i] < x && i <= last) ++i;
        while (array[j] > x && j >= first) --j;

        if (i<=j)
        {
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
            ++i;
            --j;
        }
    }

    if (j > first)
    {
        Sorting(array, first, j);
    }

    if (i < last)
    {
        Sorting(array, i, last);
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        int[] array = new int[20];

        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i<array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = random.Next(1, 20);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Sorting...");

        stopwatch.Start();

        for (int i=0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            QuickSort.Sorting(array, 0, array.Length - 1);
        }           

        stopwatch.Stop();            

        Console.WriteLine("\nCheck:");
        foreach (int x in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x + "");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Time: {0}ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        stopwatch.Reset();

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

All libraries has been connected.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered that your code is executing in less than 1 millisecond?

Comment: for benchmarks consider using BenchmarkDotNet: https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: Stopwatch is very primitive benchmark

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `Elapsed` instead of `ElapsedMilliseconds` you'll get something like :

```
Time: 00:00:00.0004201ms
```

Sorting such a tiny array doesn't even take 1 millisecond. In fact, I'd suspect the time will be affected more by writing to the console or possible thread switching.

Using 200 items returns :

```
Time: 00:00:00.0023507ms
```

Or

```
Time: 00:00:00.0050675ms
```

Each execution will give different results, because quicksort is sensitive to the relative order of the elements. Thread switching, garbage collection, other running processes will also affect the value you get.

Going for 2000 items produces results around 210-220ms. More consistent but a 5% vriation is still too big.

If you *really* want to benchmark your code, at the very least you need to test it multiple times and average the results.

A better idea would be to use BenchmarkDotNet and have it run your code long enough until it gets stable result.

Answer (score 2):

As far as your input is only 20 elements long it will take almost no time to sort it. Please try with much bigger input or try finding ticks instead of ms.

Comment: Do I have to use bigger array?

Comment: Much bigger. Try something like 100000 elements.